# highcharts - show by month

Tags: javascript, highcharts

highcharts by month no correct label, when is one month.

when is 2 month the label in xAxis is jan-2016 and feb-2016 but when is only one month the label is 04:59:59:999 
normal: https://jsfiddle.net/rcondori/c3y1r7sn/

```
series: [{
    data: [{
      name: "January",
      x: 1451624399999,
      y: 52
    }, {
      name: "February",
      x: 1454302799999,
      y: 60
    }]
  }
]
```

bad: https://jsfiddle.net/rcondori/c3y1r7sn/1/

```
series: [{
    data: [{
      name: "January",
      x: 1451624399999,
      y: 52
    }
]
```

help me please.

Comment: So you ALWAYS want to show "Month-Year" (like "Jan-2016")?

Comment: Yes, I want use "Month-Year", is there other possibility?

Comment: Great, could you please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following options:

1. Option 1
   Use Highcharts API (check [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/yyvgz4sL/)):

Highcharts.dateFormat allows you to set up the date format (for more details check this [link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.dateFormat))

```
labels: {
formatter: function() {
return Highcharts.dateFormat('%B-%Y', this.value);
}
}
```

2. Option 2:
   Using JS method:

Check below

```
var temp = new Date(this.value);
          locale = "en-ca",
            month = temp.toLocaleString(locale, {
              month: "long"
            });
          return month + '-' + temp.getFullYear();
```

By setting the variable temp as new Date (this.value), you have access to the x value (in this case the date).
month=a.toLocalString allows you to get the month on letters instead of numbers.
Here the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/ykku14e4/):

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          var temp = new Date(this.value);
          locale = "en-ca",
            month = temp.toLocaleString(locale, {
              month: "long"
            });
          return month + '-' + temp.getFullYear();
        }
      }

    },



    series: [{
        data: [{
          name: "January",
          x: 1451624399999,
          y: 52
        }]
      }

    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: I used the 1st option. Thanks you very much =)